# updating authlogic not recognizing old previous passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I was using **authlogic 3.0.0** when using **rails 3.2.2**. Now i have updated rails version to **5.1.4**. And authlogic upgraded to  **4.0.1**.

Now all of my previously saved passwords are not recognizing by authlogic. **It says invalid password**. So i have to update my password again. WHich is no desirable behavior. What changes i need to do so that my previously saved passwords work again on new authlogic version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i solve my issue,

**User.rb**

```
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512
  end
```

In version 3.4.0, the default crypto_provider was changed from Sha512 to SCrypt.

If you never set a crypto_provider and are upgrading, your passwords will break unless you set the original:

```
c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512
```

And if you want to automatically upgrade from Sha512 to SCrypt as users login:

```
c.transition_from_crypto_providers = [Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512]
c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::SCrypt
```